# Parse a document into sentences

Tags: c#, regex, linq, parsing, text

I have a question that should be simple enough to the experts but painfully mysterious to me :) I'd like to parse a text (pre-processed, no special characters except for regular punctuation marks) into sentences and perform two tasks similar to:

1. For each sentence, find the number of words (Sentence Length). Then for the document, find the average sentence length. There is no need to report any sentence-level outputs. Note that the document contains a fair number of proper nouns so the Capital letter does not necessary mean the start of the sentence. BUT the sentences in this document usually ends in ",", "!", or "?".
2. For each sentence, apply a regex pattern. If there's a match, give the sentence a value of, e.g.1. For the whole document, report the number of matches. Again, only document-level outputs are needed.

I'm wondering if there's any way to do that, preferably in C#, or VB. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

======================

Example Paragraph:

```
This is an example of a paragraph! It contains three sentences? And the average sentence has many words.
```

Example Pattern:

```
"three"
```

Output:

```
number of sentences-3.
Average sentence length-6.
Number of matches-1.
```

Comment: A sentence doesn't end in a comma. Do you mean a period?

Comment: So far the answers do not seem to account for decimal numbers and abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a sentence (depends on your definition of sentence) using:

```
(\a|[\.!\?:])[^\.!\?:]+
```

And a word using:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

The rest is easy - just look at the documentation for regular expressions on MSDN.

Comment: Finding words that way won't work. You'd miscount words with apostrophes, dashes, or anything else that could be included in a word. You could add those into your character set and use word boundaries. \b[^\s]+?\b

Comment: @Tony: That would match underscores, non-breaking spaces, and lots of other unwanted junk :) That's not my point though - he can put any character there, support multiple languages, allow digits, whatever. The definition of "word" is a bit loose.

Comment: right, I was just trying to convey that using \b for word boundaries would likely be the best way to distinguish where words begin and end.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
string example =
    "This is an example of a paragraph! It contains three sentences? And the average sentence has many words.";

var splitExample = example.Split(new[] {'.', '!', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var matchExpression = new Regex("three");
double avgLength = splitExample.Average(x => x.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length);
int sentences = splitExample.Length;
int matches = splitExample.Where(x => matchExpression.IsMatch(x)).Count();
```

Comment: "I don't think Mr. Mann can split this sentence correctly..." -- you would make that two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `Split` based off the period (.) which would give you an array of sentences.

```
string sentences[] = document.Split('.');
```

Then you would do a `Split` on each "sentence array" based on a "space" to get the number of words.

And yes you would then use Regular Expressions to do your matching.  Not much else I can add to that since you didn't specify what you're trying to match.

Comment: "BUT the sentences in this document usually ends in ".", "!", or "?"."

Comment: ahh good point, you would then need tos plit based on period question mark or exclamation.  Though it would probably be faster to do with regex.

Comment: Not really; `string sentences[] = document.Split(new char[] {'.', '!', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. (`RemoveEmptyEntries` is for ellipses.) That would probably still be faster than regular expressions.

Comment: You could also use delimiters to split sentences:

`char[] delimiters = {'!', '.', '?' };
string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);`

Comment: Not to be annoying, but: `string sentences[] = document.Split(new char[] {'.', '!', '?'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` is shorter than `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\a|[\.!\?:])[^\.!\?:]+");`

Comment: @minitech You posted yours while I was typing mine.